# Reuse a class in PySpark UDF

Tags: performance, pyspark, pickle, user-defined-functions, distributed-computing

Let's say I have a class `Foo` that I need to instantiate to run some calculations. The standard usage is:

```
f = Foo()

val1 = f.calculate(input1)
val2 = f.calculate(input2)
```

Let's suppose also that `Foo.__init__()` takes a very long time, but `Foo.calculate()` is fast.

`Foo` is provided by a library so I don't have control over the above.

I want to use `Foo` in a UDF. If I do:

```
@udf(returnType=IntegerType())
def calculate_with_foo(x):
    f = Foo()
    return f.calculate(x)
```

It will be inefficient, because `Foo` is created N times for N records. If I do:

```
f = Foo()

@udf(returnType=IntegerType())
def calculate_with_foo(x):
    return f.calculate(x)
```

I will get pickle errors, because Spark doesn't know to send `f` to the workers along with the function.

What I really want here is to have each worker instantiate `Foo` once, and reuse that object. So when I process N records over M workers, `Foo` should be called M times, not N.

How can I do this in PySpark?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to group by the Partition ID `pyspark.sql.functions.spark_partition_id()` and apply a pandas UDF for each partition.

Something like:

```
schema='x int'
def calculate_with_foo(df):
   f = Foo()
   df=df.apply(f.calculate)
   return df
df=df.groupBy(F.spark_partition_id())\
.applyInPandas(calculate_with_foo,schema)
df.show()
```

Comment: Interesting. What is your logic for why this would work?

Comment: @Dommondke with `df.groupBy(F.spark_partition_id()).applyInPandas(...)` you will slice your PySpark df in a bunch of Pandas DataFrames and apply your calculation in Pandas. Therefore `foo.__init__()` will only be called Num-Of-Partition-times.

Answer (score 1):

One other option is to transform to `rdd` and use `mapPartitions` so you can apply your heavy initialization once per partition

```py
def calculate_with_foo(partitionData):
    f = Foo() # Heavy initialization
    for row in partitionData:
        yield [row.x, f.calculate(row.x)]

df = df.rdd.mapPartitions(calculate_with_foo).toDF(["x", "foo"])
df.show()
```

The maximum number of creating a `Foo` object in this case will be the number of partitions.